# Python: how to replace the characters between fixed format of a column with another column in DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, data-processing

[image]

for example, how to replace `<Isis/>` with **twins** in the first row in the whole table?

I try to use the following codes, but Python indicates:"TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not None"

```
import pandas as pd 
import re

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

p = re.compile('<\w+/>')

df['original'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['original'].replace(
    p.match(x['original']), str(x['edit'])), axis = 1)

print(df.head())
```

I hope powerful friends help me, very anxious, thank you!

I expect the code can return the DataFrame format, and "France is ‘ hunting down its citizens who joined  ’ without trial in Iraq" can be changed to "France is ‘ hunting down its citizens who joined twins ’ without trial in Iraq".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try:

```
import re
df['original'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub("<.*?>", x['edit'], x['original']),axis=1)
```